# Apache: disable PHP in a directory

Tags: php, apache

I want to disable php in a specific directory on my server. I thought that setting Options -ExecCGI in httpd.conf would prevent php scripts from being executed, but obviously I am wrong.

So, this is what I have in my httpd.conf, which obviously does not work:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/(path_to_directory)/dirname">
    Options -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

The question is, how can I prevent php scripts from being executed in a specific folder? Can in be done in httpd.conf or do I have to use a .htaccess file?

Comment: .Htaccess is good way to do your needed operation , please check reference : https://www.dforge.net/2012/11/29/disable-php-execution-for-a-specific-folder-in-apache/

Answer (score 5):

PHP scripts are not typically handled by the CGI module.   They are usually handled by a separate PHP module with its own configuration options.  [This page](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/securing-subdirectories-with-htaccess.html) has a few examples of syntax that should do the job for you.   I expect that they would work either in your conf file or in *.htaccess*.  Try:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/(path_to_directory)/dirname">
    Options -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None        
    RemoveHandler .cgi .pl .py .php4 .pcgi4 .php .php3 .phtml .pcgi .php5 .pcgi5
    RemoveType .cgi .pl .py .php4 .pcgi4 .php .php3 .phtml .pcgi .php5 .pcgi5
</Directory>
```

OR

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/(path_to_directory)/dirname">
    AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
    Options -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

[The link](https://www.dforge.net/2012/11/29/disable-php-execution-for-a-specific-folder-in-apache/) that [Helping Hands](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/46533/helping-hands) put in the comments has a simpler way of removing all handlers by setting them all to the default and removing all options with "None":

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/(path_to_directory)/dirname">
    SetHandler default-handler
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding this line to your virtual host seems to work: `php_value engine off`

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/(path_to_directory)/dirname">
   php_value engine off

   # other options
</Directory>
```

On Debian, the file would be located in the folder `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

Comment: Thanks, for mod_php this worked just fine. And I used `<Location...` instead of `<Directory..`.

Comment: 2020 - Works. Linux Apache box