# .htaccess - How to properly disable the execution of scripts in a folder?

Tags: htaccess

I have this folder path: `pulic_html/user/269851516/`in the folder `/user/` i have many subfolders that is created when the user create a account, and they can upload avatars to this folder, i want to disable the execution of scripts in this folder, so i created a `.htaccess` and put in `public_html/user/`:

```
<Files *>
    SetHandler none
    SetHandler default-handler

    Options -ExecCGI
    php_flag engine off
    RemoveHandler .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo
</Files>
```

with this code inside my `.htaccess` nobody can execute scripts in this folder (i gues...).
I have searched about it a bit, and i found different ways to do it, so i don't know if i did it correctly, and if there's something missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with this code inside my `.htaccess` nobody can execute scripts in this folder (i gues...).

The only way to know whether it works "on your server" is to test it. If it works on *your server* to block direct script access (from the client) for the type of scripts that you are trying to block then "it works".

With the many different servers, there isn't necessarily a single/best way to do this. The directives you posted are arguably "generic" - designed to work across several different servers. You don't need all of them.

`SetHandler none`, `SetHandler default-handler` and `RemoveHandler` all do the same sort of thing so I can't imagine they are all required. It's likely that different server configs require different settings.

`php_flag engine off` will only work when PHP is installed as an Apache module. It won't work if PHP is running as CGI/FastCGI - in fact, you may even get a 500 internal server error!

The only change I would perhaps make is to change `Options -ExecCGI` to the more encompassing `Options None`. This also disables `Includes` (server-sides includes), `Indexes` (directory listings) etc. But it's possible these are already disabled in your server config.

The `<Files>` wrapper may be required on some servers if using the `SetHandler`/`RemoveHandler` method to block running scripts. Whilst `<Files *>` simply targets every file, as if there is no wrapper at all, it changes the order of execution so the directives run later - to ensure they override any earlier `AddHandler` directives.

---

**UPDATED:**

However, to clarify... this doesn't necessarily "disable the execution of scripts in a folder". It prevents the *client* (user-agent / browser) from making direct (HTTP) requests to scripts in a directory. Any script can still be executed in this directory if it is "called" (eg. included) from another script elsewhere on your system.

For example, say you have protected the `/public_html/user` directory tree with a `.htaccess` file at `/public_html/user/.htaccess` and you have another PHP script elsewhere on your filesystem, say at `/public_html/foo/bar.php` and `bar.php` has a statement like:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].`/user/myavatar.jpg`);
```

Then `myavatar.jpg` will still be "executed", despite `/user/.htaccess` disabling script access to this directory. (In this contrived example, `myavatar.jpg` is not a JPG image, but a PHP script containing `<?php` blocks - the file extension is irrelevant). The `.htaccess` file is only processed for direct HTTP access, not filesystem access from other scripts.

See also this related question:

- [Apache: disable PHP in a directory](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74668/apache-disable-php-in-a-directory)

Comment: you said: `this doesn't necessarily "disable the execution of scripts in a folder"`. Are you talking about this? `<FILES>` and `<Directory>` from this link: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/74669/93636 what is the difference? I put my `.htaccess` in `public_html/user/` and any .php file that is on the subfolders inside `/user/` is not being executed. So i don't know what are you tring to say

Comment: No, nothing to do with `<Files>` and `<Directory>` containers. The linked question is about using the main server config, not `.htaccess`. In the main server config, you need to use `<Directory>` containers instead of `.htaccess` files to target a particular directory tree. `<Directory>` is not permitted in `.htaccess`. I've updated my answer with an example explaining what I mean.

Comment: there's is another way to call this file without direct HTTP access and PHP? I mean, could someone call (include) this file using the devTool? I can retrive the data from a file using Ajax call, but i don't if it's possible to do a non HTTP reques on the devTool

Comment: What's "the devTool"? (Chrome's DevTools? - No, that's just an HTTP request.) I was just stating how the script _could_ potentially be run within that directory (that is otherwise "secured" by `.htaccess`) - whether that is actually possible or not on your system is another matter entirely. (There would need to be other potential vulnerabilities on your site for that to happen - site hacked, rogue plugin, bad coding, .... etc.)